# ubuntu 14.04 ros indigo installation dependecies errors

Tags: ros, ubuntu, packages, ubuntu-trusty, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello
I have a Ubuntu 14.04 LTS system. I am following the instructions from http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Ubuntu to install on this system ROS Indigo.

At 1.4 Installation, when I get to the point `sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-desktop-full`, I get the following error messages:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-indigo-desktop-full : Depends: ros-indigo-desktop but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: ros-indigo-perception but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: ros-indigo-simulators but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Can you please advice how to overcome this error?
Thank you all.
George

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/249047/ubuntu-14.04-ros-indigo-installation-dependecies-errors/) by [gmadamide](https://answers.ros.org/users/28655/gmadamide/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2016-11-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ruo](https://answers.ros.org/users/28670/ruo/) on 2016-11-30**:
Hi, did you solve the problem?
i meet is too,

**Comment by [gmadamide](https://answers.ros.org/users/28655/gmadamide/) on 2016-12-01**:
No, not yet

**Comment by [gmadamide](https://answers.ros.org/users/28655/gmadamide/) on 2016-12-08**:
Yes the issue was solved. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi thank you for your answer.
Actually it seems that the problem was that instead of installing it on ubuntu 14.04, I was running ubuntu 16.04. So, after installing ubuntu 14.04, I managed (following the instructions wiki.ros.org to install indigo without any problem.

---

Originally posted by [gmadamide](https://answers.ros.org/users/28655/gmadamide/) with karma: 18 on 2016-12-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0